# Install package using stack.yaml config

Tags: haskell-stack

I'm trying to install `yi`.

I've got the following `stack.yaml` file:

```
resolver: lts-8.12
extra-deps:
- yi-frontend-pango-0.13.5
```

A `stack install yi` gives me an error of: `Stack looks for packages in the directories configured in the 'packages' variable defined in your stack.yaml`.

Am I only able to install this via editing my global `stack.yaml` config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full error should be something like

> Stack looks for packages in the directories configured in the
>   'packages' variable defined in your stack.yaml The current entry
>   points to /home/mgsloan/fpco/test-stack/stack-overflow-43575553/ but
>   no .cabal file could be found there.

The issue is that the `packages` field defaults to the current directory, since it's a common use case to use it with just one package.  You can override this by doing the following:

```
packages: []
```